# How to make a system event application in c#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make the following. I have a class that at midmight it makes a log from what happened in a SQL table and makes an excel file of it. My issue is that I was told that it is inexcusable to have this application running all day only to have it run once a day and that I should do this with a system event, but I have no idea how to do this. Help, please?

Comment: Windows task scheduler should be all you need!

Comment: Of course, how could I have forgotten. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use Windows' built in Scheduled Task support to run your app.  Or, if you're using Microsoft Sql Server, a scheduled Sql Agent job.

Comment: Once again I missed the obvious. Thank you.